# why is my event.type==pygame.K_ not working?

Tags: python, events, if-statement, key, pygame

keep in mind there is more code before this, and other imports linked to here, but that does not have to do with my problem.

I would like to know why my event.type==pygame.K_RIGHT command is not working.
When I run the code, it says no errors but the player can not move.

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)

movex, movey = 0,0

while gameLoop:


 for event in pygame.event.get():

    if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):

        gameLoop=False

    if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

        if (event.type==pygame.K_d):

            movex=5

        elif (event.type==pygame.K_a) :

            movex=-5

    if (event.type==pygame.KEYUP):

        if (event.type==pygame.K_RIGHT):

            movex=0

        elif (event.type==pygame.K_LEFT) :

            movex=0

window.fill (blue)
player.render(window)

player.x+=movex

clock.tick(60) 
pygame.display.flip()
```

pygame.quit()

Answer (score 2):

Once the `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP` event has been detected, you need to check the `event.key` attribute rather than `event.type` to know which key was pressed. Something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    # The KEYDOWN event was posted
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        # The down arrow key was pressed
        # Note the key attribute is being checked rather than type
        if event.key == pygame.KEY_DOWN:
            # do something

        # The right arrow key was pressed
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.type==pygame.K_RIGHT):
  movex=0
```

You have put movex= 0 hence the player is not moving. You need to change it. Change it to movex = 1.